# How to check the next empty line in textpad and append the next input

Tags: java, swing, file-io

Hi I am having problem with my UI. Currently, I want my UI to append input into a textpad everytime it click save. After the save button is clicked, it will return to a menu to ask if the user want to enter another input. If the user click yes, it will return to input section. However when I try inputing the second time, it will overwrite what I have written initially. How do I change my code in order to resolve this issue?

```
  private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BufferedWriter output = null;
         FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            File myFile = new File("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/sample.txt");
            fs = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/sample.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
             myFile.createNewFile();
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
            //output.flush();
            for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line.equals(null)){
                   String name = text1.getText();
                   String id = text2.getText();
                   output.write(name + " " + id);
                   break;
                }

            }
           // output.newLine();




        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

       this.dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However when I try inputing the second time, it will overwrite what I have written initially.

Open the `FileWriter` in append mode.

Read the `FileWriter` API to find the appropriate constructor to use.

Answer (score 1):

A new sample.txt is being created even before reading from the old one here. One way could be to read the text input into a String and add new line character ("\n") with new output and concatenate with the input to create the new same file.

Comment: The newline character (`'\n'`) does not actually create a line break; use `System.lineSeparator()` to get the line break for a file writer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all especially to camickr and Kesavacharan. Below is my edited version. Please feel free to comment if you find that my code can be improved.

```
 private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        BufferedWriter output = null;
         FileInputStream fs = null;
         FileWriter fout = null;
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            File myFile = new File("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/sample.txt");
            fs = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/kai/Desktop/sample.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile,true));
            PrintWriter fileout = new PrintWriter(output,true);
            for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i){
                String line = br.readLine();
                if(line==null){
                   String name = text1.getText();
                   String id = text2.getText();
                   fileout.println(name + " " + id);
                   break;
                }
            }




        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(setup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

       this.dispose();
    }
```